# Displaying the year using angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to display two year values on my screen using angular 4. The first is current year and the second is current year plus 7. Could you please let me know if I am doing it the correct way

**component code**

```
  currentYear = new Date();
  currentYearPlusSix = new Date();
  currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setDate(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7 );
```

**html**

```
 The current year is {{currentYear | date:'yyyy'}}
  The current year plus six is {{currentYearPlusSix1 | date:'yyyy'}}
```

Comment: i don't see any problems in the code

Comment: did you mean `setFullYear`?

Comment: No there is no problem at the moment and it is displaying the right values. I just want to ensure if it is the right and best way of doing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setFullYear` to set the Year, not `setDate`.

`setDate` is clearly a wrong usage, and will give a wrong result.

```
 currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setFullYear(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7 );
```

`setDate` accepts `dayValue` - An integer representing the day of the month. If you pass an year to it, you will get a different result

```js
currentYear = new Date();
currentYearPlusSix = new Date();
currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setDate(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7);

console.log(currentYearPlusSix)
```

Use `setFullYear` instead to change the years

```js
currentYear = new Date();
currentYearPlusSix = new Date();
currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setFullYear(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7);

console.log(currentYearPlusSix)
```

Comment: Noted. Is there a shorter way of doing things or are the number of variable declarations corrects

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please make the following change:

```
currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setFullYear(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7 );
```

setDate will only add days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setFullYear`

```
currentYearPlusSix1 = this.currentYearPlusSix.setFullYear(this.currentYearPlusSix.getFullYear() + 7 );
```

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/setfullyear-method-date-javascript)  for more information.